# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a functionat <anonymous>:1:13

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a play video attribut on Jquery. I a seeing the error below when I try itin the console.

from console

```
a[i_number]
"ONXZOOlmFbM"

$('#video').attr("src", 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/+ a[i_number] +?autoplay=1')
```

error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a functionat <anonymous>:1:13
```

Comment: If you're getting that error it means that `$` no longer refers to `jQuery`. Also note that the string you're using in the setter is not correctly formatted, as you can see in the syntax highlighting in the question - you're missing the quotes around the concatenated value.

Comment: (or never referred to jquery in the first place, eg if you didn't include jquery.js or your include failed for some reason (eg 403))

Comment: Keep in mind, in some browsers `$` in the console will be defined as something other than jQuery, if jQuery is not included on the page.  Because, ya know, why not make things confusing.